# SSRS changing values based upon other values

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have ran into a problem with my report.

This drop down needs to adjust the values in the PeriodStart/PeriodEnd

### [image]

When the Weekly Period is changed, these values need to change. Although, I want to keep the default values before Weekly Period is changed.

### [image]

So lets say that the drop down has its value as 10/1/12 | 10/7/12. I am assuming I will change the expression of the two date fields and do some kind of split on the drop down value, but I am not sure what that would be. This is where I need guidance. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am not near Report Builder right now, but it should go something like this:

1) make your weekly period drop down a datetime field with the value of the start date, and the label in whatever format you like.

2) set your period start date parameter to be a datetime field, and in the Default Values tab, set the default value to be the expression `=Parameters!WeeklyPeriod.Value`

3) set your period end date parameter to be a datetime field, and in the Default Values tab, set the default value to be the expressions `=DateAdd("d", 7, Parameters!WeeklyPeriod.Value)`

Comment: Thanks, two problems though:

1. The drop down is not required, so I need the date fields to default to the values shown in the question unless the drop down is changed.

2. The dates get filled correctly the first time I change the value of the drop down but ignores the ensuing changes.

Comment: on the last (advanced?) tab of the parameter dialog, does changing the refresh setting help?

Comment: No, it does not change the outcome